# Getting Messages by MessageId in Logic App

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

Is there any way in Azure Logic App to get Service Bus Message by MessageId? I can see there are actions to get the message by identifiers such as sequence number and sessionid, but not messageid.

Comment: You may also try using Serverless360 where you can just get the messages using MessageId using a simple search feature. You can receive the messages in any mode - peek lock, deferred mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure logic apps does not have a connector to get messages based on messageId, and I have not found an API to get messages using messageId.

Comment: Thanks, we are getting the message by sequence number after deferring them.